# Solr : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on replication handler

Tags: java, solr

I am using the 5.3.0 solr and I am getting the following error on solr replication handler-

```
1007316 WARN  (qtp922434038-18) [   x:core1] o.e.j.s.ServletHandler Error for /solr/core1/replication
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler$DirectoryFileStream.initWrite(ReplicationHandler.java:1341)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler$DirectoryFileStream.write(ReplicationHandler.java:1374)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$9.write(SolrCore.java:2184)
        at org.apache.solr.response.QueryResponseWriterUtil.writeQueryResponse(QueryResponseWriterUtil.java:50)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.writeResponse(HttpSolrCall.java:742)
```

anyone help me to fix this issue occuring by configuring java properties or by any other way.

thanks in advance..

Comment: You could try increasing the -Xms/-Xmx JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: I already given 8 g  max heap still it is consuming all memory- 
bin/solr restart -a "-Xmx8g" -p 8983

Comment: How frequently is this happening? Is it happening at the same place always?